# How to get value from TD column using this.value

Tags: javascript

```
<table>
<tr  onClick = "alert(this.FirstTDValue);" >

    <td>123</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Goodbye</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

How would this.FirstTDValue be accomplished so that alert would show '123', would it be efficient to request it at the TR or the Table level?

Comment: I imagine you would have to give the first <td> an id so it knows where to look and take the values from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Table rows have a *cells* collection that is a live NodeList of the cells, so:

```
alert(this.cells[0].textContent || this.cells[0].innerText);
```

Or perhaps:

```
alert(this.cells[0].firstChild.data);
```

Answer (score 3):

`<tr>` elements have a `cells` collection that lets you access the child `<td>` elements:

`this.cells[0].innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

```
<tr  onClick = "getTD();" >

<td>123</td>
<td>Hello</td>
<td>Goodbye</td>

</tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getTD(){
   alert(document.body.getElementsByTagName("td")[0]);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Only works if this is the first row in the first table of the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
<script>
Element.prototype.FirstTDValue = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i< this.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if (this.childNodes[i].tagName == 'TD') {
            return this.childNodes[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }
    return ("No TD Values");
}
</script>
<table>
<tr  onClick = "alert(this.FirstTDValue())" >

    <td>123</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Goodbye</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Instead of looping over `childNodes`, you can take the first element of `children`.

Comment: Depending on *Element.prototype* support is worth a -1 ... lucky escape. This time. :-\

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Solution:

```
<tr onClick="alert( $(this).children().first().text() )" >
```